# how to show max date for primary key in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
with bookingdetails as (
    select  booking_master.booking_datetime as newdatetime, 
            booking_master.ETA as neweta 
    from booking_master where booking_ID='143'
)
```

The output for above is:

```
newdatetime             neweta
2016-10-02 03:00:00.000 2016-10-05 03:00:00.000
```

Than I run this:

```
with comparetrucklog as (
    select  truck_log.truck_id as bookedtruck, 
            truck_log.ETA as eta 
    from truck_log 
    where (select newdatetime from bookingdetails) between truck_log.pickupdate and truck_log.ETA 
        or (select neweta from bookingdetails) between truck_log.pickupdate and truck_log.ETA
)
```

In the result for `comparetrucklog` in bookedtruck column 37 is repeated twice but I need to display only the **maximum** datetime in `eta`.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need all `bookedtruck` that have `MAX(eta)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why simple max() will work right?

```
 select bookedtruck, max(eta) from bookingmaster group by bookedtruck
```

Comment: You can get these info by just googling it

Comment: I tried all  complex ways .missing this simple one .some times it happens bro. sry-:).